# a problem configuring tex4ht after OCT TL update

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, adjustbox

I found another problem using tex4ht in mathjax mode after updating TL 2020 two night ago.
Something that was working, now does not work.

I had solution that allowed me to use a `\newcommand` correctly in PDF and tex4ht modes. I posted about this here. [how-to-make-tex4ht-ignore-some-commands-automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568244/how-to-make-tex4ht-ignore-some-commands-automatically)

The solution posted above no longer works after I updated TL. Now I get

[image]

on the web page.

I made a small MWE below and a sample .cfg used and the command I use.

What changed in tex4ht that could have caused this now not to work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\myadjustbox[2][0.98]{% %default width: 0.9\textwidth
\ifdefined\HCode
  {$\displaystyle #2$}
\else 
   \adjustbox{max width=#1\linewidth}{$\displaystyle #2$}
\fi 
}{%
}

\begin{document}

%why this below no longer work in mathjax mode?
\underline{Solution by CAS}
\[
\myadjustbox{ y \left(x \right) = x^{2}+x +3}
\]

\underline{Solution by CAS}
\[
y \left(x \right) = x^{2}+x +3
\]    
\end{document}
```

The command to compile is

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug -c my.cfg foo.tex  "mathjax,htm"
```

The HTML page shows this

[image]

While 2 days ago before updating TL, it displayed OK both cases.

This needs `my.cfg` in order to tell mathjax about `\myadjustbox` as per the answer linked to above. Here is the .cfg file. This is not the full .cfg I use, but tried to post only the relevent parts needed to show the problem.

```
\Preamble{xhtml,p-width}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{ 
 <script id="MathJax-script" async
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js" id="MathJax-script">
    </script>
\Hnewline}}

%V3.0
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script>
window.MathJax = {  
  tex: {
    maxBuffer: 40*1024,
    packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']},
    \unexpanded{%
    macros: {      
        sp: "^",
        sb: "_",      
      noalign: ["\#1", 1],
      myadjustbox: ["\#1", 1],      
    }},
    autoload: {
      color: [],
      colorV2: ['color']
    },
    packages: {'[+]': ['noerrors','textmacros']}
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',
    processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/noerrors','[tex]/textmacros']
  }
};
</script>\Hnewline
}}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I also put the above 2 files and result of compiling in a small zip file on my page. Please see this [zip file](https://www.12000.org/tmp/tex4ht_issue/nov_23_2020.zip)  if it makes it easier instead of copying the above manually.

TL 2020 on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax configuration is now customizable using `\Configure` command. Two new options are provided, `MathjaxSource` and `MathJaxConfig`. They can be used in the following way:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,p-width}
\Configure{MathjaxSource}{https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js}
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{  
  tex: {
    maxBuffer: 40*1024,
    packages: {'[+]': ['textmacros']},
    \unexpanded{%
    macros: {      
        sp: "^",
        sb: "_",      
      noalign: ["\#1", 1],
      myadjustbox: ["\#1", 1],      
    }},
    autoload: {
      color: [],
      colorV2: ['color']
    },
    packages: {'[+]': ['noerrors','textmacros']}
  },
  options: {
    ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore',
    processHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_process'
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/noerrors','[tex]/textmacros']
  }
};
}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The produced HTML file looks correctly with this change:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I changed my .cfg and now it works.